# multiple collisions or drugging

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have two types of collision. First one is the spaceShip and asteroid (this is already handled) but I can't handle second type of collisions, where my spaceShipLazer hits enemySpaceShips. In second case I have drugging/multiple collisions or sometimes perfect collision.

My enemySpaceShip is an EnemySpaceShip class which is a subclass of SKSpriteNode.

So the question is about second collision. Is has multiple collisions that is not expected. How I can fix it?

```
  func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == CollisionCategories.PlayerSpaceShip && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == CollisionCategories.Asteroid || contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == CollisionCategories.PlayerSpaceShip && contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == CollisionCategories.Asteroid {

      if !gameOver && !playerWasHit {

        playerWasHit = true
        self.pauseTheGame()

        //spaceShip vs asteroid animation
        let fadeOutAction = SKAction.fadeOutWithDuration(0.1)
        fadeOutAction.timingMode = SKActionTimingMode.EaseOut

        let fadeInAction = SKAction.fadeInWithDuration(0.1)
        fadeInAction.timingMode = SKActionTimingMode.EaseOut

        let blinkAction = SKAction.sequence([fadeOutAction, fadeInAction])
        let blinkRepeatAction = SKAction.repeatAction(blinkAction, count: 3)

        let delayAction = SKAction.waitForDuration(0.2)

        let gameOverAction = SKAction.runBlock({ () -> Void in

          self.gameSettings.lives--
          self.gameDelegate?.gameDelegateDidUpdateLives()

          if self.gameSettings.lives > 0 {

            self.respawn()
          } else {

            self.gameSettings.recordScores(self.gameSettings.currentScore)
            self.gameDelegate?.gameDelegateGameOver(self.gameSettings.currentScore)
            self.gameOver = true
            self.pauseTheGame()

          }
        })

        let gameOverSequence = SKAction.sequence([blinkRepeatAction, delayAction, gameOverAction])
        spaceShipLayer.runAction(gameOverSequence)
      }

      if soundOn {
        let hitSoundAction = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("hitSound.wav", waitForCompletion: true)
        runAction(hitSoundAction)
      }
      //second case playerLazer vs enemySpaceShip
    } else if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == CollisionCategories.PlayerLaser && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == CollisionCategories.EnemySpaceShip || contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == CollisionCategories.PlayerLaser && contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == CollisionCategories.EnemySpaceShip {

        contact.bodyA.node?.removeFromParent()
        contact.bodyB.node?.removeFromParent()


      }
    }
```

Comment: What *is* your question? You're saying what you have, but there's not even a single question mark in your text. What do you want to know?

Comment: @uliwitness been disturb and forgot to add. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found decision that makes everything perfect:

just second part should be like this:
if

```
contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == CollisionCategories.PlayerLaser &&
      contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == CollisionCategories.EnemySpaceShip ||
      contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == CollisionCategories.EnemySpaceShip &&
      contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == CollisionCategories.PlayerLaser
    {

      contact.bodyA.node?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = CollisionCategories.None
      contact.bodyB.node?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = CollisionCategories.None
        contact.bodyA.node?.removeFromParent()
        contact.bodyB.node?.removeFromParent()
        self.addPoints(5)

    }
  }
```

So I've made .None categoryBitMask and applied it after collision detection so now points and spriteNode behavior is correct!